# Struct pointer that can point to any inherited structs

Tags: c++, inheritance, struct, polymorphism

I have structs set up as such:

```
struct A {
    int aInt;
    string aString;
};

struct B : A {
    int bInt;
    string bString;
};

struct C : A {
    int cInt;
    string cString;
};

struct D : B {
    int dInt;
    string dString;
}
```

I would like to be able to declare an `A *` and be able to allocate any of B, C, or D to that pointer. For example, any of the following:

```
A *ptr = new B;

A *ptr = new C;

A *ptr = new D;
```

In doing this, I am not allowed to access any of the the values that are not natively part of A. For example:

```
ptr->bInt
```

raises a compiler issue. Is what I'm trying to achieve possible, or will C++ not let me use structs in this manner?

Comment: So the question is what are you expecting to happen if you have your pointer to `A` and you try to access `bInt` but it just so happens that your pointer is not pointing to a `B`. The answer to that question will determine the best approach.

Comment: This will not happen in my case, and I'm okay with a segfault or exception.

Comment: Well in that case I would just cast the pointer `static_cast<B*>(ptr)->bInt` If you are wrong this will give you *undefined behaviour*, not necessarily a segfault. The alternative would be to add a `getBInt` virtual function to `A` and `B`.

Comment: If you know the pointee object class, then use `static_cast`, if don't, use `dynamic_cast`. That question was asked yesterday.

Comment: cout <<(reinterpret_cast<B*>(ptrB))->bInt<<endl;
cout <<(static_cast<B*>(ptrB))->bInt<<endl;
cout <<((B*)(ptrB))->bInt<<endl;

Comment: In response to @john suggestion of using `getBInt`, what would this look like?

Comment: @nvn If you make those 3 suggestions, please point out the issues with these. using `reinterpret_cast` here is bad; It disables some checks by the compiler that could help detect issues, like trying to cast to a class `E` that is completely unrelated to `A`; Imho this shouldn't be a recommendation in this scenario at all for this reason. The C-style cast is even worse, since it allows you to ignore const...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the basic pattern for polymorphism. The virtual destructor is required if you ever want to write `delete ptr;` (which surely you do).

```
struct A
{
    virtual ~A() {}
    virtual int getBint() { throw std::exception("wrong type"); }
};

struct B : A
{
    int getBint() override { return bInt; }
    int bInt;
}l
```